# Keycloak with multiple django servers

Tags: python, django, authentication, keycloak

I would like to ask for advice about this problem.
My current setup with single django server and keycloak is this:

for login handling, I am using django-allauth library
([django-allauth](https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/)

All bellow steps are assuming, user is working in browser.
Keycloak serves as user provider and login service for django:

- user goes to django.server/login
- user is redirected to keycloak login page
- user logs in
- backend checks if user exists in django DB, if not, creates it (this is done by django-allauth)
- user is redirected to django home page

all after-login user activities with django does not require keycloak anymore.. all permission hadnling is done by pure django (django.contrib.auth). user is identified through session.
I am not using any keycloak functionalities (resources, scopes,...) EXCEPT roles (roles are synced to django as groups)

My current problem is this:
What if I have multiple django servers and I want them to communicate with each other with permissions of logged in user?

Example:
User visits djangoServer_A view which requests djangoServer_B view (which requires some authentication) and response of djangoServer_B view is returned to django_server_A view...

Some pseudo-code:

```
# djangoServer_A
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def serverA_view(request):
  serverB_response = call_serverB_view(**some_parameters)
  return serverB_response

# djangoServer_B
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def serverB_view(request):
  if request.user.has_perm("some_permission"):
    return "Hello World"
  else:
    return "You do not have required permission"
```

Some other userful information

- each django server has its own database (therefore each django server has its own User instances in DB)
- logging in to any django server uses the same keycloak realm and set of users
- Python 3.12
- Django 5
- The solution needs to work on both standard, and API views (probably done by django-rest-framework)

My potential solution to this is this:

1. Setup multiple clients in keycloak (one for every django server)
2. When user logs in to ServerA, during logging in I store some keycloak tokens (refresh token)
3. When processing serverA_view I request from keycloak some access token and I push it with request to serverB_view.
4. (This part is where my understanding is really weak...) On serverB I receive request with this token and I somehow verify it through keycloak and authenticate the user, then the serverB_view can process request. But I am not sure if I can authenticate user this way on django...

I will be grateful for either some direction, solution, or materials to study.
Thank you